# Numpy data alignment when slicing

Tags: python, numpy, alignment, slice

I do the following:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt

x = genfromtxt('foo.csv',delimiter=',',usecols=(0,1))

y = genfromtxt('foo.csv',delimiter=',',usecols=(2),dtype=str)
```

Then I enter:

```
x[y=='y1Out',0] # assume the set of "y" is 'y1Out' and 'y2Out'
```

That command prints all the "0 column" values in "x" that have an associated "y" value equal to `y1Out`. How is this possible? That is, how does numpy keep track of the alignment between "x" and "y"? I thought numpy doesn't have data alignment.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `y == 'y10ut'` and `y` is an array of `dtype` string, numpy returns a boolean array with the indices of `y` where the condition is met. E.g.:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.empty(10, dtype='S8')
# populating the array with 'y10ut' and 'y20ut' alternatively
y[1::2] = 'y10ut'
y[::2] = 'y20ut'
```

then you can evaluate the condition:

```
>>> y == 'y10ut'
array([False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,
       True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

And this resulting array can be used as an index array for `x`. Note that if `y` is not an array of strings, the resulting evaluation is no longer an index array:

```
>>> y = np.arange(5, dtype='f')
>>> y == 'y10ut'
False
```

In your case, numpy doesn't know the relation between `x` and `y`. But given the condition `y == 'y10ut'`, it will index the first dimension of `x` according to it, which seems to be what you want.